# How to run container using image id or name?

Tags: apache, docker

I have created an apache server image from tar file using below command,

```
cat /home/ubuntu/docker-work/softwares/httpd-2.4.27.tar.gz | docker import - httpd:2.4
```

The image is created successfully and its name is httpd!

I have run below command,

```
 docker run -d -p 80:80 --name=apache  httpd:2.4
```

which is giving error,

> docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.

How do I run the above image using the name(httpd) ?

Comment: Can you add response of "docker images" ........

Comment: REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
httpd               2.4                 13522dff2d5c        42 minutes ago      37.6MB

Comment: you can use "docker run  -p 80:80 --name=apache 13522dff2d5c" command

Comment: Getting this error: docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.

Comment: try this " docker run hello-world" it it works means your docker is installed correctly

Comment: Docker is installed correctly and " docker run hello-world" worked fine!

Comment: Show your Dockerfile, in particulat the lines CMD and ENTRYPOINT

Comment: I haven't written dockerfile. I just ran commands on console

Answer (score 3):

The error that you are getting means that the image import from the tar doesn't container a default command `CMD` line to start the container.

Docker allows you to not specify the CMD in the docker file, however in that case you need to provide the command when doing docker run. Example:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name=apache  httpd:2.4 httpd-foreground
```

Where httpd-foreground is the command that will start the httpd server process inside the container.

Comment: Ran this :  docker run -d -p 80:80 --name=apache  httpd:2.4 httpd-foreground

Comment: Got the error: docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"httpd-foreground\": executable file not found in $PATH".

Comment: Then just try to execute the following:

`docker run -itd -p 80:80 --name=apache  httpd:2.4 /bin/bash`, get the container ID, and then run `docker attach <container_id>` to attach to the container and troubleshoot.

Comment: Getting this error: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory"
Error: failed to start containers: cd1bc95911e1